# Removing first character from layers using ArcPy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arccatalog

How to remove the "w" from these file geodatabase classes using ArcPy?

Tried this code snippet but does not work:

[image]

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:\shared\NCWD\Testing\Castic_FGDB.gdb"
in_data = "wValve"
out_data = "Valve"
arcpy.Delete_management(out_data)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this?  The error messages provided by Python are always informative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since your in_data variable is a string you should be able to use in_data[1:] to get the string without the first character.

Edit:
Sorry, I think I misread your question. I think you want to know how to remove the first character for all files in the file geodatabase. To do so you want to list all inside the database and loop through it and perform the Rename function.

For reference:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/rename.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/listing-data.htm

Answer (score 4):

Discovered the correct script!

```
import os

import arcpy
arcpy.

env.workspace = "C:/shared/NCWD/Testing/Castic_FGDB.gdb"

fcs = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("c*","All","cWaterDistributionNetwork")

for fc in fcs:

      print(fc)
      arcpy.Rename_management(fc,fc[1:])
print "all done"
```